# Selecting phrases in Emacs rather than words or sentences

Tags: region, selection, writing

`Notabene` word processor has an interesting command that allows one to select phrases, i.e. one selects text up to the next punctuation mark.

Hence, in this example:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
```

Shift+Control+f12 selects first

`Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,`

a second invocation expands the region to

`Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.`

and so on.

Phrases with quotes are selected as follows:

`"The man on the moon."`

I would like to replicate this behavior in Emacs, as it is very helpful for the kind of academic writing I do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `M-e` (bound to `forward-sentence`). It doesn't quite do what you are asking, but tweaking the user option `sentence-end` (which you should read about with `C-h v sentence-end`) should allow you to do what you want. Here is a possible setting:

```
(setq sentence-end "[.,;!?:'\"] ")
```

which seems to work for the above cases, although I have not tested much beyond that. The regexp matches any of the punctuation characters inside the square brackets when followed by a space.

In use, you set the mark at the beginning with `C-@` or `C-<space>` and then `M-e` repeatedly to expand the region.

Comment: I tried `M-e`. In my case it moves the cursor to the end of line. (Same as `C-e`) Any idea why? Sometimes I would like to move the cursor sentence by sentence.

Comment: I found the answer here: https://flylib.com/books/en/2.27.1.29/1/ It seems that emacs requires two spaces after the period to recognize it as a sentence. Is there a way around this?

Comment: The setting above requires only one space after the puncuatiion. It might cause problems in other situations though, precisely because of that convention.